# ¿Como crear una función para organizar un texto?

Tags: python

resulta que debo leer un archivo de texto como este:

***“Enero,4,3,4;Febrero,4,3;Marzo,4,3,4;Abril,4,3,4,4-Daniel”***

y lo que debo hacer es crear un función que lo organize de la siguiente forma:

***['Daniel', {'Enero': 11, 'Febrero': 7, 'Marzo': 11, 'Abril': 15}]***

la entrada del Código seria obviamente algo como esto:

```
print(Organizar("Enero,4,3,4;Febrero,4,3;Marzo,4,3,4;Abril,4,3,4,4-Daniel"))
```

y su salida seria:

```
['Daniel', {'Enero': 11, 'Febrero': 7, 'Marzo': 11, 'Abril': 15}]
```

alguien tiene idea como hacer esto?

Comment: hay una pregunta igual

Comment: en donde esta Christian?

Comment: gracias christian

Comment: Hola. StackOverflow es un sitio para preguntas de programación. Lo que tu has publicado es la descripción de un trabajo para un programador o de una tarea en un curso de programación, y ese tipo de preguntas suelen no ser bienvenidas en el sitio. Una pregunta sería más que bienvenida si intentas resolver el ejercicio por ti mismo y, al encontrar alguna dificultad, vienes a plantear **ese problema**, con todos sus detalles. Para más información lee [ask].